# How do you calculate force in a cone full of fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have no idea how to calculate the force the sides of the cone exert to the fluid (when the cone is at least partly filled with fluid)
Can someone help me? A link or a short explanation will do

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the author has shown zero effort, which in a sense makes the question vague. What *exactly* has you stuck? You say you have "no idea" how to do the calculation but that's probably not true. Can you make even the first baby step?

Comment: I typed "force of container containing fluid" into Google and found the answer to this question in the third result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the pressure exerted on the cone by the liquid?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226324/what-is-the-pressure-exerted-on-the-cone-by-the-liquid), though that has no answers and is likely to be closed as a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the force the cone exerts on the fluid should be the same magnitude as the force the fluid exerts on the cone (my undergrad professor called this *Newton-Three*).  Presumably, you know either the mass of the fluid, or can find it from its density and volume (from the cone's geometry), and can find the force of gravity, that is the force of the fluid on the cone, from there.